# Symfony form submission redirect to a page and display what user just inputted

Tags: forms, symfony, redirect, submit, twig

new to Symfony. I've created a form for submission and I want it to redirect to a 1) submit success page that displays what the user just submitted and 2) an error page if the fields were entered incorrectly. However, when I enter fields and submit it just takes me to the same page with empty fields.

I have my controller:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
     {
       $newperson = new Person();       
      $personform = $this->createForm(new PersonType(), $newperson);

    if($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $personform->bind($this->getRequest());
        if($personform->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($newperson);
            $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cir_submitsuccess'));

        }
    }           
    return $this->render('CIRBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'personform'    => $personform->createView()
    ));             
}
```

My routing.yml:

```
cir_submitsuccess:
pattern: /submit
defaults: { _controller: CIRBundle:Validation:index }
```

And my index.html.twig:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

{% if person is defined %}
     <ul>
     {% for person in person %}
        <li>{{person.firstname}} {{person.lastname}} who is {{person.age}} years old and works as a {{person.position}} living in {{person.city}}
     {% endfor %}
     </ul>
     {%endif%}
  <br/>
 {% endblock %}
```

Validation controller:

```
class ValidationController extends Controller
{   
public function indexAction() {

     return $this->render('CIRBundle:Validatiion:index.html.twig');     
}   
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the route `cir_submitsuccess`?

Comment: @Alberto Fernández I did, you mean the routing.yml correct?

Comment: I was talking about the `Validation` controller.

Comment: Alright, just edited.

Answer (score 0):

If when you submit, you are getting an empty form, then it would seem that the validation is failing and you are falling through to displaying the form again.

If the form validates and you redirect, that will be a new request, so that doesn't have any information about which person you want to show details for. You would have to pass something in the route to identify the person so that you can load their entity from the database and pass it to the template.